# Updating DOM element with AJAX return data fails in jQuery

Tags: html, xml, jquery

I'm doing a simple AJAX post request in jQuery to another page on my site to get an XML document response. I'm putting the response into a `pre` element with syntax highlighting enabled. The response comes through fine (I can `alert` it), but it isn't being added to the`pre` element when I attempt to assign it in the `handlResponse` function with jQuery.

```
<head>
<script>
   ...
   function handleResponse(response, status)
   {
      $("#output").text(response);
   }
   $.post(url, data, handleResponse, "text");
   ...
</script>
</head>

...

<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

Just to be clear, the javascript code above is in jQuery's document ready function. Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, if I had to guess one thing, it would be changing the callback to `handleResponse()`, but I always get messed up on when to use the () and when to leave them out in js, so I always end up doing the wrong one first...

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what the response text might be?  I've just run a mock of this in jsbin.com and it works fine for my example

Comment: Sorry all, the issue was unfortunately unrelated to jquery and ajax. see my answer below. I have to wait a few days to accept it, so sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a bad question. I'm using the javascript lib [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/) and had preloaded the syntax highlighting on the `pre` tag I was attempting to use. My solution was to remove the tag and dynamically create it when the ajax response comes in. This worked well other than the fact that I'm trying to determine how to load the highlighting on a dynamically appended dom element.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `html` instead of `text`...

```
$("#output").html(response);
```

**EDIT:** If you think escaping is the issue, the following should escape it well enough to display...

```
response = response.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
$("#output").html(response);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to escape the response, as it is XML and would be improperly added to the `pre` element.

Comment: And just to ensure I'm not crazy, I tried that, and it also does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. Is the response being passed correctly? Check by doing alert of response from within the function itself.
2. Is the function being called correctly? Check by having it do an alert unrelated to the response variable (`alert("Yo!")`).
3. Is the text being inserted correctly? I can tell it should work, but for sake of full debug, add a ternary like this:

   ```
   var preText = (response != "") ? response : "The problem is with the reponse";
   ```

Comment: I didn't add my debugging in the question above, but i've done string alerts as well as alerting the response, and both work fine.

Comment: Within the function itself? That part is key. The function is getting called and likes the variable, etc....

Comment: And you can set something else inside the `text()` does it show up the way the response is not?

Comment: Oh, and just for giggles, try adding this after the text is set to response... `alert($("#output").text());`  If it still shows the response, maybe the problem is just something CRAZY, like the pre is hidden.